# Flutter chat bubble - How to add column without making the bubble to be the same size?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a messaging/chat app. Got to the point where I am starting to like the output (Needs styling for sure).
[image]

This is my current code:

```dart
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final Note note;

  const MessageBubble({Key? key, required this.note}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(
            opacity: 0.4,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text(DateFormat('HH:mm').format(note.date),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .bodyLarge
                      ?.copyWith(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75),
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      note.text,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I think adding the time within the bubble is better than it being outside.

I tried adding the text in a column and started with:

```dart
child: Column(
                  children: [
                    //If a topic category is present add that here
                    Text(..logic for topic if present)
                    Text(
                      note.text,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                    //Timestamp
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        const FaIcon(
                          //FontAwesomeIcons.boxArchive,
                          FontAwesomeIcons.clock,
                          size: 12,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          DateFormat('HH:mm').format(note.date),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

The whole thing becomes equal size container.
[image]

Is there a way to still keep this chat bubble ratio like the earlier image but have like topic (top left) if present and time (bottom right)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stack` like this:

```dart
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final Note note;

  const MessageBubble({Key? key, required this.note}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildContent(context, note.text),
          if (note.topic != null) _buildTopic(note.topic),
          _buildTimeStamp(note.date),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context, String text) => Container(
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  text,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildTopic(String topic) => Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(
            topic,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildTimeStamp(DateTime date) => Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.clock, size: 12, color: Colors.grey),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
            Text(
              DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 5),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am going to attempt with Stacks. I appreciate you sharing the code as well. The position looks off, and I need to control the size now so the timestamps do not look bad.